# How to call a method that has been overridden by an extension method?

Tags: python

I have a class with a `plot` method, like this:

```
class A:
    def plot(self):
        ...
```

and I wrote an extension method like this:

```
def plot(self):
    ...
    self.plot()

A.plot = plot
```

but this will produce a recursive call. How can I resolve this problem without changing the method name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold onto its previous value:

```
_plot = A.plot

def plot(self):
    _plot(self)

A.plot = plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use monkey patch on class or only one instance. See the following smaple code, `setattr(A, 'method_to_patch', new_method_on_class)` override the method defined in class A. So, `method_to_override` in both instance a and b has been patched. `TypeMethod` can patch instance only. So, only instance a has been patched.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.words = 'testing'

    def method_to_patch(self):
        print ('words: {}'.format(self.words))


def new_method_on_class(self):
    print ('class: patched and words: {}'.format(self.words))


def new_method_on_instance(self):
    print ('instance: patched and words: {}'.format(self.words))

a = A()
b = A()
a.method_to_patch()

setattr(A, 'method_to_patch', new_method_on_class)

a.method_to_patch()
b.method_to_patch()

a.method_to_patch = types.MethodType(new_method_on_instance, a)

a.method_to_patch()
b.method_to_patch()
```

Output:

> words: testing
>
> class: patched and words: testing
>
> class: patched and words: testing
>
> instance: patched and words: testing
>
> class: patched and words: testing

Comment: Thanks! I had learned how to extension method to an instance from your answer.

Comment: But I found that `a.method_to_patch = types.MethodType(new_method_on_instance, a, A)` must be changed to `a.method_to_patch = types.MethodType(new_method_on_instance, a)`

Comment: you are correct. `MethodType` only takes 2 args in python 3. I have updated my answer. Thanks